# How does Flask know to load the views.py in the Visual Studio default Flask Solution?

Tags: python, visual-studio, flask

I'm using the Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS 2.2 Beta) and creating a new Flask Web Project with Visual Studio 2013.  (btw I'm new to both Flask and Python...)

The views.py contains my routes.  How does VS know to load this file?  I don't see it in any properties or other files.  Is it a default to always have the routes in views.py?

My goal is to use Flask to build a RESTful API and I'm tempted to just replace everything in the views.py with my API routes.  Or, can I add another .py file for the API routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flask it is usually enough to import the files the routed functions are defined in. You can add your API methods in an other file and import it. Make sure you don't have any circular imports, they are a source of problem in Flask quite often.

If things are getting more complex, it's best to use Blueprints to bundle routes together.

Comment: I see in __init__.py the line:  import FlaskApiTodo.views.  Is this importing my views.py?  So, if I define a new file called restapi.py and then add import FlaskApiTodo.restapi it would be OK?  Can you give an example of a circular import?

Comment: An example: File `a.py` imports `b.py` and later defines a function `func1()`. In file `b.py` you import `func1` from `a.py`. Now a the result if `a.py` is run at the times it import `b.py` if jumps into `b.py` and want to import `a`, a is imported already, so it checks `a` for `funct1`. But it is no present since the code defining the function was no run, yet. The result of a circular import is an ImportError or an AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks, I added this line to the __init__.py and it is working  import FlaskApiTodo.restapi